# LINQ to Entities- SaveChanges take too much time

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

Currently, I am struggling with an issue regarding Entity Framework (LINQ to Entities). Most of the time when I try to execute entity.SaveChanges() everything works fine but at some points entity.SaveChanges() takes too much and timesouts. I searched a lot but was unable to find out the answer.

(According to companies policy, I cannot copy code somewhere else. So, I do not have the exact code but I will try to layout the basic structure. I hope it helps you to figure out the problem but if i doesn't then let me know.)

Task: 
My task is to scan the whole network for some specific files. Match content of each file with the content of database and based on the matching either insert or update the database with the content of the file. I have around 3000 files on the network.

Problem:

```
public void PerformAction()
{
    DbTransaction tran = null;
    entity.Connection.Open();    //entity is a global variable declared like myDatabaseEntity entity = new myDatabaseEntity();
    tran = entity.Connection.BeginTransaction();

    foreach(string path in listOfPaths)
    {
       //returns 1 - Multiple matching in database OR
       // 2 -  One matching file in database OR
       // 3 -  No Matching found.
       int returnValue = SearchDatabase();      

       if(returnValue == 1)
          DoSomething(); //All inserts/updates work perfectly. Save changes also works correctly.
       else if(returnValue == 2)
          DoSomething(); //Again, everything ok. SaveChanges works perfectly here.
       else
       {
           //This function uses some XML file to generate all the queries dynamically
           //Forexample INSERT INTO TABLEA(1,2,3);
           GenerateInsertQueriesFromXML();

           ExecuteQueries();

           SaveChanges(); <---- Problem here. Sometimes take too much time.
       }
       //Transaction commit/rollback code here
    }    
}


public bool ExecuteQueries()
{
   int result = 0;
   foreach(string query in listOfInsertQueries)
   {
      result = entity.ExecuteStoreCommand(query); //Execute the insert queries

      if(result <=0)
        return false;
   }

   entity.TestEntityA a = new entity.TestEntityA();
   a.PropertyA = 123;
   a.PropertyB = 345;
   //I have around 25 properties here

   entity.AddToTestEntityA(a);

   return true;    
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to insert a lot of data at once, try breaking it out into multiple `SaveChanges()`. However, at this point we can only guess at what your problem is. You might want to ask your co-workers, who can see your code.

Comment: Well, i actually insert data for each file on the network and then close the transaction and start a new one for the new file. In each iteration i do around 20 insertions only.

Comment: Fact is EntityFramework isn't very good for bulk inserts. However it does look like your `DbContext` is a member field. You should know that `DbContext`s should be disposed of as quickly as possible, you shouldn't reuse a context.

Comment: Try to write a stored procedure... I too had the same problem.. And i ended up writing stored procedure.

Comment: @SanjooUthaiahBollera I cannot move to stored procedures right now.

Comment: @Aron So, after processing each file I should dispose the DBcontext and create a new one ? What is the reason for this ?

Comment: Many reasons. In your case, because it keeps the size of the ChangeTracker small so when you do `SaveChanges` the ChangeTracker only have to diff a limited number of objects.

Comment: okay. I will try you solution and will update you in 3-4 days. ( I am on holidays for a few days)

Comment: @All, I figured out the problem. It was not related to Entity Framework. There was a trigger (INSERT,DELETE) on the main table. Whenever i inserted something in the main table, the trigger fired and did its own processing (which was taking time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

The main table where i was inserting all the data had a trigger on INSERT and DELETE.

So, whenever i inserted some new data in the main table, the trigger was firing in the backend and was taking all the time.

Entity framework is FAST and INNOCENT :D